# Area behind twitter bootstrap modal windows gets invalidated after dismiss

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, area

I'm facing a weird issue when using twitter bootstrap modal windows. Everything works ok when the size of the browser is desktop, the problem appears when the size of the browser is phone. Of course, it also fails on a real phone.

In that case, after the modal window is dismissed, the area that was behind the modal window gets invalidated. I mean, the anchors behind the area that was occupied by the modal window doesn't work after the modal window dissapears. Even if I click refresh in the browser the anchors still don't work. I have to resize the browser to desktop size for those anchors to work again.

Has anybody experienced anything like this?  Any ideas about how to solve it?

Comment: Can you post your modal code?

Comment: I can't post the original code, it's too long. So I'm trying to write something like the real thing but smaller. But this new code works... it's clear I'm doing something wrong but I cannot find it. I've asked just in case anybody else had experienced the same. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the problem. My mistake, I had a couple of wrong things, on one side, I mixed the .hide and .hidden classes for one of the modals divs. That was wrong, and on the other hand, I had a

```
$('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
```

instruction at another part of the code, and as a result this collateral problem was happening, but only when the size was phone. Crazy stuff.